# Understanding Polar of a set

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

So I am very new to the idea of polar set and trying to solve a few questions to get a hang of it.   Below are the two questions that I am trying to solve:

> The polar of a ball of radius $r$ with centre at the origin.

My approach is: The polar of $A$ can be defined as:
$A^\circ =  \{y \in R^d : \langle x,y \rangle \leq 1 \}$ and its also the intersection of all the halfspaces satisfying the above equation. Then intuitively I believe it will be a ball. Even I read in this https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-409-topics-in-theoretical-computer-science-an-algorithmists-toolkit-fall-2009/lecture-notes/MIT18_409F09_scribe11.pdf that it will be a ball of $1/r$ radius. But it does not show how exactly it is done. I saw a similar question on the stack where they use some standard norm in the equation but I exactly did not get why they use it.

My second question is :

> what will be polar of that is a  hyperplane passing through the origin.

I do think these are very simple question but since I am new to this that's I am not able to grab the concept properly and I am finding it difficult to solve. Any explanation or help is appreciated.

Comment: It might help to compute the polar of a single point, that is $A= \{x\}$ for $x \neq 0$. Consider $y$ parallel & perpendicular to $x$ initially. (Maybe start with $d=1,2$.)

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you for your answer and explanation. In the last para are you referring to orthogonal of A and span of{a}. I did not much understand the last paragraph

Comment: @ Actually what I thought or rather imagined for the second question that the polar of A will the subspace satisfying the equation less than 0 i.e$ a_1x_1+.. +a_nx_n < 0$

Comment: I added a little more detail. Feel free to ask for elaboration.

Comment: @copper.hat If you don't mind could you please elaborate

Comment: Of course, but you need to let me know where the sticking points are. Also, it is probably better if you add comments to my answer.

Comment: @copper.hat like why$ A\circ =A^T$. And I understood why the ball has a 1/r radius. But I did not understand why A is invariant in the case of rotation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $A^\circ =  \cap_{x \in A}\{y \in R^d | \langle x,y \rangle \leq 1 \} = \cap_{x \in A}\{x\}^\circ$. It should be clear that $A^\circ$ is always convex and closed.

For intuition, note that since $\{x\}^\circ = \{y | \langle x,y \rangle \leq 1 \} $, we see that if $x =0$ then  $\{x\}^\circ = \mathbb{R}^d$ otherwise
$\{x\}^\circ$ is a half space with normal $x$ and shortest distance from the origin to the boundary is ${1 \over \|x\|}$. It may help to sketch $\{x\}^\circ$ for a few points in the plane.

If $r>0$, then it is straightforward to check that $(r A)^\circ = {1 \over r} A^\circ$. Hence it is sufficient to find the polar of $A = \{ x | \|x\| \le 1 \}$.

Another useful result is that if $L$ is an invertible linear transformation, then $(LA)^\circ = (L^T)^{-1} A^ \circ$. This is straightforward to show from the definition.

There are various approaches one can take here. One simple one is to notice from the previous result that if $A$ is invariant under rotations by orthogonal matrices, then so is $A^\circ$. In particular, $A^\circ$ must be a closed ball and it is easy to check that the radius is one, hence $A^\circ = A$.

For the second question, $A = \{ a \}^\bot = \{ y | \langle y , a \rangle = 0 \}$ for some $a$. In particular, $A$ is a subspace. It is not too hard to check from the definition that if $A$ is a subspace, then $A^\circ = A^\bot$, and in this case we have $A^\circ = (\{ a \}^\bot)^\bot = \operatorname{sp} \{a\} = \{ \lambda a | \lambda \in \mathbb{R} \}$.

**Clarification**:

Suppose $L$ is an invertible linear transformation. Then
\begin{eqnarray}
(LA)^\circ &=& \{ y | \langle y , Lx \rangle \le 1, \text{ for all } x \in A \} \\
&=& \{ y | \langle L^Ty , x \rangle \le 1, \text{ for all } x \in A \} \\
&=& \{ (L^T)^{-1} z | \langle z , x \rangle \le 1, \text{ for all } x \in A \} \\
&=& (L^T)^{-1} A^ \circ
\end{eqnarray}

Suppose $A$ is a subspace. Suppose $y \in A^\circ$. Then $\langle y , x \rangle \le 1$ for all $x \in A$. Since $A$ is a subspace, $t x \in A$ for all $t$ and so $t \langle y , x \rangle \le 1$ for all $t$. Then only way this can be true is if $\langle y , x \rangle = 0$. Hence $y \in A^\bot$ and so $A^\circ \subset A^\bot$.

For the other way around, it is immediate that if $y \in A^\bot$ then $y \in A^\circ$ (since $0 < 1$).

Comment: are you taking span of a because for any value of a the equation =0 will always be less than 1 like in case of singleton when x=0 the polar is R^d

Comment: I did understand that you are taking some orthogonal vector for which the dot product will be zero and hence satisfy the equation. But again why you took polar as orthogonal of it I did not get

Comment: @Delta I added a clarification.

Comment: thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Why the downvote?